# Install php trader on xampp 8.0.13 and run in all sorts of problems

Tags: php

First it was the :

> " Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer
> supported "

That got sorted out via previous posts here.Thank you.

Then I got this error after running cmd:

```
pear trader upgrade
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in
> C:\xampp\php\pear\Console\Getopt.php:135 Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\php\pear\Console\Getopt.php(74): Console_Getopt::doGetopt(2, Array, 'c:C:d:D:Gh?sSqu...', NULL, false)
> #1 C:\xampp\php\pear\pearcmd.php(71): Console_Getopt::getopt2(Array, 'c:C:d:D:Gh?sSqu...')
> #2 {main}   thrown in C:\xampp\php\pear\Console\Getopt.php on line 135.

I understand that the "each($args)" - function has been deprecated, but way is it still in the `Getopt.php` script? Is there any way it can be resolved?

Comment: Presumably the product you've installed does not support PHP 8. Contact the supplier (or check their documentation) to see what PHP versions they _do_ support, and/or whether they have an updated version of the product available, or are planning to update it in the future.

Comment: The php installation comes standard with the xampp installation.

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about the package version of the thing you're trying to upgrade - presumably whatever version of php trader you've installed isn't ready for PHP 8. Is it this package: https://pecl.php.net/package/trader ? Version 0.5.1 says it supports PHP 8 - https://pecl.php.net/package/trader/0.5.1